# Create a list of dictionaries with random small alphabet letters as a key and as a random value number from 1-50

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

- number of dictionaries in a list random from 2 to 15
- dictionary length is random

for example: [{'d': 15, 'c': 9, 'g': 18, 'm': 33, 's': 10}, {'a': 9, 'h': 50, 'r': 15}]

I would like to use list comprehension, and I started from this:

```
import string 
letter_count = dict((key, 0) for key in
string.ascii_lowercase) print(letter_count)

number_of_dictionaries = 3 # should be random
list_of_dictionaries = [dict() for number in range(number_of_dictionaries)]
```

I have no idea how to make random key and letters not in order.

Comment: Are you aware of the `random` module? https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

Comment: Yep, but I have no idea how to implement it there with random keys and letters

Comment: You generate random numbers for the things you marked as such for a start....

Comment: What are the bounds on the dictionary length?

Comment: there is no bound on the dictionary length

Answer (score 1):

Since the letters will be the keys, you need to select non-repeating random letters (which you can do using random.sample).  the dictionary can be created by pairing up the letters with a list of random numbers using zip():

```
import string 
import random

size   = 10
keys   = random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase,size)
values = (random.randint(1,50) for _ in range(size))
result = dict(zip(keys,values))

print(result)
{'r': 43, 't': 40, 'o': 18, 'm': 8, 'f': 47, 'a': 21, 'y': 50, 'b': 44,
 'i': 42, 'w': 31}
```

To get multiple dictionaries in a list, you can combine this approach in a loop selecting a random size for each (in range 1-26).

```
dictList = []
for _ in range(random.randint(2,15)): # random number of dictionaries
    size    = random.randint(1,26)    # random dictionary size
    keys    = random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase,size)  # random letters
    values  = (random.randint(1,50) for _ in range(size)) # random numbers
    oneDict = dict(zip(keys,values))                      # assemble dict.
    dictList.append(oneDict)                              # add it to the list

print(dictList)

[{'u': 14, 'j': 49}, 
 {'y': 32}, 
 {'y': 7, 'c': 26}, 
 {'p': 11, 'k': 20, 'n': 6}, 
 {'h': 4, 'f': 35, 'w': 19, 'n': 19, 'g': 25, 'p': 4, 'k': 36},
 {'h': 47}]
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation